# CXF version Upgrade from 2.7.7 to 3.1.8 JAXB IllegalAnnotationException is thrown

Tags: rest, soap, jaxb, cxf

I am upgrade the cxf version  to 3.1.8 from 2.7.7. Facing so many issues and fixed one by one.

But finally facing JAXB IllegalAnnotationException which is not coming with 2.7.7. In 3.1.8 , the JAXB-IMPL version is 2.2.11 and in CXF 2.7.7 JAXB-IMPL version is 2.2.5 I tried with JAXB-IMPL 2.2.5 with CXF 3.1.8, facing the same issue.

I am new CXF API and not sure what is the problem with newer version. Anyone help is more appreciated.

Comment: [INFO] com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 40 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions [INFO] at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException$Builder.check(IllegalAnnotationsException.java:66) ~[na:1.6.0_07] [INFO] at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getTypeInfoSet(JAXBContextImpl.java:422) ~[na:1.6.0_07] [INFO] at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.(JAXBContextImpl.java:270) ~[na:1.6.0_07] with different types like

Class has two propertys with the same name. It is an Interface, JAXB cannnot handle.

Comment: I tried with JAXB-impl with the older version which is 2.2.5 , even tough getting the same exception.

Can any one please guide me what is the exact root cause. Why it is working with older version with out any exceptions.. Struggling this issues with the last few days. Anyone help is much appreciated